# Qt server and android ssl client Certificates

Tags: java, android, qt

I Use `Qt`as server side,and  `android` as client side. 
I set in `SSLSocketFactory` certification

```
    private ConnectionManager(MBoxConfiguration config) {
    try {
        this.config = config;


         try {
                trusted.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

          SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
          Socket socket;
          socket = ssf.createSocket();
      socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(config.ip, config.port));
           KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        InputStream in = MainActivity.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
        try {

            trusted.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
             ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);                                                                                                                   


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

When I want connect to server, in `QT` is give me that error

`Thread Address in peerVerifyError "The peer did not present any certificate" 
     Thread Address in sslErrors ("The peer did not present any certificate") 
       Thread Address in error QAbstractSocket::SocketError( 13 ) 
     Thread Address in destroyThreadfirst:  QThread(0x12ec9448) 
     Thread Address in destroyThread:  QThread(0x12ec9238)`

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qsslsocket.html

Look at the description of QSslSocket::sslErrors

Try to hook up `sslErrors` signal and then call the slot `ignoreSslErrors()` from there to ignore the errors, that should help.